# Docker React container making '/favicon.ico' to server and how to handle it

Tags: reactjs, docker, google-cloud-platform, favicon

[Request Made](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPfcI.png)

I am hosting my MERN stack by containerizing in GCP it with docker compose , it was running fine , but my react app keeps on making request to this endpoint /favicon.ico.

[my index.html file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFjWJ.png)

I tried inserting the following in the head tag of index.html but no response to the change tha same error persisted

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is the problem? Web browsers request `favicon.ico`. You can either ignore that request or serve the file. Nothing different from serving any image.